# insert into statement with where clause dynamically

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table with columns name, date time, Sunday, Monday, ....Saturday. I have a c# application which has a datagridview  and combo box column for weekday  where i want to insert one value  to a column dynamically.
 when I try to select Sunday from combo box and enter 10 in a text box it should insert a new row in  the table. 
here is what i have done.. how to insert into single column based on combo box selected value.

```
 string Query = " Insert into [VCS].[dbo].[PA Report]([Name],[Date time],[Sunday]) values ('" + this.textBox1.Text +'" where  ?????????"'; "; );";

            SqlConnection conDatabase = new SqlConnection(constring);
            SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDatabase);

            SqlDataReader myReader;
            try
            {
                conDatabase.Open();

                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
                MessageBox.Show("saved");
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
```

Comment: First thing to fix: use parameterized SQL rather than building the SQL itself dynamically...

Comment: Are data values that appear in, say, the `Monday` column something that is *logically* different from values that may appear in the `Thursday` column? If not, then your data structure is incorrect. You ought to design data structures that store data *as* data, not by how it's formatted or displayed. This ought to be a single column with a name that indicates what this value represents, and, *if necessary* a separate column which stores the day of the week (but this would seem to be redundant if you're also storing the date).

Comment: how to asssume a combobox columnn as database column .. I dont know much about sql but i am thinking like insert into table (column) values ( textbox1.text) where date =17/01/2014. where column value = combobx1.selected value. can we do like this.